# Hover не работает

Tags: jquery

Есть такая конструкция

```
<a class="video-item-thumb" href="/">
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="chaimg">бла</div>
  </div>
  <span class="ico ico-play"></span>
</a>
```

Сколько не пытался, hover по chaimg не работает

```
$(".chaimg").hover(
  alert('ok');
)
```

Comment: А вы в документации видели примеры? https://api.jquery.com/hover/     ..............      http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F_hover

Comment: был виноват css.

Comment: Разве в аргументы не нужно передать функцию?
$(".chaimg").hover(function() {
    console.log("Привет, я отрабатываю");
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $('.video-item-thumb').on({
 mouseenter: function () {
    alert('ok');
}
}, '.chaimg');
```

Answer (score 2):

Разве в аргументы не нужно передать функцию которую необходимо выполнить?

```
$(".chaimg").hover(function() {
    console.log("Привет, я отрабатываю");
});
```

Возможно ваши блоки сгенерированы динамически, поэтому событие написанное так, отрабатывать не будет, в таком случае вам поможет подобная конструкция:

```
$("body").on("hover", ".chaimg", function() {
    console.log("Привет, я отрабатываю на динамически-созданных блоках");
});
```

Так же в событии hover, можно передать вторую функцию, которая выполниться при обратной ситуации, а именно когда курсор ушел с блока:

```
$("body").on("hover", ".chaimg", function() {
    console.log("Привет, я отрабатываю на динамически-созданных блоках");
}, function() {
    console.log("А я отрабатываю, когда курсор ушел с блока");
});
```